# Исчез ActionBar на Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, actionbar

На устройстве Samsung SM-N7505 Android 4.4.2 не отображается ActionBar (На устройстве с Android 4.2.1 все норм)

```
         <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"> 

        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
           {... }
```

отказываться от ActionBar? или это решается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все решается вот таким вот методом:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>


</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Понимаю, что это не ответ на ваш вопрос, но отказывайтесь от ActionBar. Это устаревшая вещь. Используйте Toolbar. Это избавит вас от вашей проблемы и предоставит много других возможностей. Подробный туториал здесь публиковать смысла нет, поэтому почитайте об этом либо [здесь на русском](http://androiddocs.ru/toolbar-alternativa-actionbar/), но лучше [здесь на английском](http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-app.html).

Comment: saturov, спасибо. В данный момент просто не успеваю переделывать :) Нету времени на это... Придется на пока оставить)